# problem in htaccess regex phrase

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert this url:

```
module-apple-get.html?term=st
```

to

```
file.php?module=apple&func=get&term=st
```

I 've wrote this code in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^module-apple-get\.html?term=([^-]+)$ file.php?module=apple&func=get&term=$1 [L,NC,NS]
```

but it doesn't work.is it wrong?

Comment: have you tried this: `RewriteRule ^module-apple-get\.html\?term=(.*)$ file.php?module=apple&func=get&term=$1` ?

Comment: yes,i tried it but it doesn't work.it seems it don't mind about anything after \.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` directive doe not work with query string directly therefore your rule will never work.

Here are few approaches.

**1)** This will do the rewrite if `/module-apple-get.html` is requested and will append existing query string to the new URL. This means, that if you request `/module-apple-get.html?term=st&some=another_param` it will be rewritten to `file.php?module=apple&func=get&term=st&some=another_param`. This is a safer and recommended approach.

```
RewriteRule ^module-apple-get\.html$ file.php?module=apple&func=get [QSA,L]
```

**2)** Another approach is to ONLY rewrite if requested URL has `term=st` PRESENT:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)term=st
RewriteRule ^module-apple-get\.html$ file.php?module=apple&func=get&term=st [L]
```

This will rewrite if you request `/module-apple-get.html?term=st` but will do NOTHING if you request `/module-apple-get.html?some=another_param`.

**3)** Yet another approach is to ONLY rewrite if WHOLE requested URL matches:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^term=st$
RewriteRule ^module-apple-get\.html$ file.php?module=apple&func=get&term=st [L]
```

This will rewrite if you request `/module-apple-get.html?term=st` but will do NOTHING if you request `/module-apple-get.html?term=st&some=another_param`.

**P.S.**

1. You can add any other flags if required (`[NC]`, `[NS]` etc).
2. You may need to add leading slash `/` before `file.php` (depends on your setup, where this .htaccess is located etc)